# How to still keep the automatic InDesign page shuffling while starting a new section on the left or right side?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout

I have a document in InDesign and I need to start a section on the left side, but InDesign only allows me to do this if shuffling is set to manual. This means that if I need to add a page at the beginning of the document, I need to manually shift all the pages.

Any better ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can start a section on a left page: right-click on the desired page (let's say page 4) and select Numbering and section options.

Check Start section and choose automatic page numbering. If you do want a custom page number, it needs to be an even number to remain on the left side.